# Eloquent Relationships No Output

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new to Eloquent Relationship and all in all in Laravel. I am trying to figure out a way to do many-to many relationship but somehow, I am getting `no output`. Basically my intention is to clarify the concepts of Eloquent Relationships which is why, I have changed the default table name as well as placed all the models and controllers into separate folders. Although namespacing isn't giving a problem but I believe Eloquent relationships is giving some sort of a problem. Below mentioned is all my code.

Models: `namespace App\Relationship_Model;`

```
class roles_model extends Model
{
    protected $table="roles_table";
    public $timestamps=false;

    public function users_table()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(users_model::class);
    }
}

class users_model extends Model
{
    protected $table="users_table";
    public $timestamps=false;

    public function roles_table()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany(roles_model::class);   
    }
}
class roles_users_model extends Model
{
    public $timestamps=false;
    protected $table="roles_users_table";


}
```

Controller: `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Relationship_Controller;`

```
use App\Relationship_Model\roles_model;
use App\Relationship_Model\users_model;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $role=users_model::find(1)->roles_model;
        dd($role);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the columns you have defined. Follow the documentation regarding column naming https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many (Also it would be easier if you'd use proper cased class names etc. but that aside)

Comment: It's hard to check issue with this post, but have you tried it like: `$role = User::find(1)->role->name;` ??

Comment: Try this `$role=users_model::find(1)->roles_table;`

Comment: @FarazIrfan it throws an exception if I write `roles_table`.

Comment: Can someone tell me in this statement `users_model::find(1)->roles_model;`, is it correct that in place of `users_model`, we have to write the name of the user model, in place of `roles_model`, we must place, roles model name?

Comment: Try this $userWithRole=users_model::with('roles_table')->find(1);

Comment: @FarazIrfan Still getting an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do many to many, you don't need a third model like yours : `roles_users_model` unless you it's an entity which belongs to many users and belongs to many roles.

Laravel uses is own naming convention. It's recommended to follow theses naming.
But in your case you will have to specify with your own parameters :

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
```

Références :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many
https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions

Comment: My Roles_Model is contained in a folder named Relationship_Model. So do I have to use `App\Relationship_Model`?

Comment: You can use the namespace as a string like the example, or with the static `class` attribute as you already do

Comment: I have already mentioned namespaces on the top of the classes so as I said, namespaces aren't causing a problem. Something else is.

Comment: I never said your problem was the namespace. You need to complete the parameters. Laravel will try to look for a table named probably "roles_table_users_table".

Comment: I tried adding the parameters you have mentioned above in the `users_model` but it simply throws an exception.

Comment: What did you add and what was the exception?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel_test.user_id' doesn't exist (SQL: select `roles_table`.*, `user_id`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id`, `user_id`.`roles_model_id` as `pivot_roles_model_id` from `roles_table` inner join `user_id` on `roles_table`.`id` = `user_id`.`roles_model_id` where `user_id`.`role_id` in (1))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171050/discussion-between-cbaconnier-and-dontdownvoteme).

Comment: Okay!, see you in the chatroom